# Is it true that every function f satisfies $f(2n) = Θ(f(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to determine if this statement is correct or not:

```
Every function f satisfies f(2n) = Θ(f(n))
```

Where, as I understand it, $f(2n)$ cannot be bounded by $f(n)$, as:

```
f(n) ≤ f(2n)
```

Since $2n$ is twice that of $n$, making me think that simply by definition of being multiplied by $2$, it will encapsulate $f(n)$.

So does this mean that $f(2n)$ cannot be bounded by $f(n)$, (since something cannot be bounded by the thing it is already greater than?)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=2^x$. The function $2^{2n}$ grows far faster than $2^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off: there's no reason to suspect that $f(2n)\geq f(n)$.  Take, for instance, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ (or any other function which is decreasing).

To say that $f(2n)=\Theta(f(n))$ means that $f(2n)$ is eventually bounded *on both sides* by constant multiples of $f(n)$.  So, to disprove this result, you would need to find a function which grows (much) faster and faster as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Look up the definition of $\Theta$.  The requirement $f(2n)=\Theta(f(n))$ says $k_1f(n) \le f(2n) \le k_2f(n)$  For $f(n)=3n$, this is correct-take $k_1=2, k_2=4$.  For $f(n)=x^2$ it is still true-take $k_1=1, k_2=5$.  But for $f(n)=2^n...$